# Bootstrap Nav Tabs Showing All Body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make my Nav Tabs Section not show all body of each tab photo below.

Here is my Code for the relevant section:

```
 <div class="widget-content padding">
                                <a href="consultants.html" style= "float:right" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button></a>
                            <h1>Sales Provisioning - (Daniel Ince)</h1> 
                        </div>
                        <br>
                            <div class="additional-btn">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content padding">
                            <h3><i>Refer to FAQ if you get stuck whilst Provisioning</i></h3>
                            <br>
                            <ul id="demo1" class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#DOT" data-toggle="tab">DOT <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#BizEssentials" data-toggle="tab">BizEssentials <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="#NewLine" data-toggle="tab">New Line <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a href="#NewMobile" data-toggle="tab">New Mobile <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#TMB" data-toggle="tab">TMB <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="#0365" data-toggle="tab">0365 / Mobile Apps <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#Appointments" data-toggle="tab">Appointments <span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Here is what it looks like:
Picture Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icI46.png

Below the Red Line is how I need it to display.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out.

Error is in each tab body with an (Active Fade in)
Where it should be (Fade in) not the above.